# Java: Assign sorted map keys via stream to an array

Tags: java, java-8, stream, hashmap

I am trying to assign map keys to an integer array after sorting the map.

This is what am trying:

```
java.util.stream.Stream<Map.Entry<Integer,Integer>> sorted = 
                            myMap.entrySet().stream().sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue());
```

and then this is how am assigning:

```
int [] hotels = new int[myMap.size()];
int i = 0;

Set<Integer> keys = myMap.keySet();
for(Integer k:keys){
       hotels[i++] = k;
}
```

But when I print the array, it does not print in sorted order but regular map order.

I know a method: `forEach(System.out:: println)` to print the values in the stream itself but not able to assign.

Whats the correct way?

Comment: Well, the second snippet doesn't use the stream created in the first snippet. So why would the keys be sorted? map() the entries to their key, then mapToInt(), then toArray().

Comment: How? Thats what am asking. Not aware of the java 8 libraries much.

Comment: Then read the javadoc. That's what it's for. I gave you the method names. Shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: Alright. Will take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your stream is not sorting the entry set of the map in place. Additionally, just calling `sorted` doesn't run any sorting code (there's no terminal operation executed).

You can use this to get an array sorted through your stream:

```
int[] hotels = myMap.entrySet().stream()
                .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())
                .mapToInt(Map.Entry::getKey)
                .toArray();
```